# implied by the 'yield*' expression must be assignable to

Tags: flutter, dart

This is same question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484679/the-type-implied-by-the-yield-expression-must-be-assingable-to),
But in my case I didn't get right solution for convert future to stream functio.

Here is my `Future` function.

```
Future<List<Message>> messageList() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _db!.query('Test',orderBy: 'timestamp DESC',);
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Message(
          inboxId: maps[i]['inboxId'],
          messageId: maps[i]['messageId'],
          fromId: maps[i]['fromId']
      );
    }
    );
  }
```

And this is `Stream`

```
Stream<List<Message>> streamMessage() async* {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _db!.query('Test',orderBy: 'timestamp DESC',);
    List<Message>list=List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Message(
          inboxId: maps[i]['inboxId'],
          messageId: maps[i]['messageId'],
          fromId: maps[i]['fromId']
      );
    }
    );
    yield* list;//// at this point IDE shows red error
  }
```

error:

```
The type 'List<Message>' implied by the 'yield*' expression must be assignable to 'Stream<List<Message>>'.
```

Comment: The "yield *" is unpacking the elements of the List, but you want a single yield of the entire list.  So remove the * and just yield list.  Or change your return value to Stream<Message>.

Comment: Generally, in an `async*` function you would want some form of loop, so that your stream has more than one event. As currently written, your function will always yield the one list and end - and really no different from your version that returns a future.

Comment: Look in the language spec https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf under section 18.17 "yield each".  I think it has been in there since the beginning.

Comment: Note that because the method is `async*` the expression after `yield*` must be a stream: `If m is marked async* (9), then: It is a dynamic type error if the class of o is not a subtype of Stream<Tf >.` `yield*` isn't going to "unpack the list" except in a `sync*` method. Here it would listen to the stream and emit events of type `List<Message>` until the stream ends, then move to the next statement (which here will exit from the method). The compile time error is generated because `list` is not a stream; which is why it should be `yield` not `yield*`.

Comment: by the lack of english language, still I didn't figure out how to solve this ?

Comment: Change `yield* list` to `yield list`.